# Sonata Admin Override template depend of user

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I try to override layout template in Sonata Admin but depends of logged user. If logged user belong to group customers has some ROLE  - show other layout.

I want change -

```
layout" => "@SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig"
```

Where is best place to do it ?

I found that i can do this in admin class - override getTemplate.

But is possible to do this is some listener and switch globaly without edit admin classes ?

UPDATE 1

i create class

```
class SonataTemplateRegistry implements MutableTemplateRegistryInterface
{

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $templates = [];

    /**
     * @param string[] $templates
     * @param ContactService $contactService
     */
    public function __construct(array $templates = [], ContactService $contactService)
    {

        $templates['layout']= '@SonataAdmin/layout1.html.twig';
//        $templates['layout']= '@SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig';

//        echo '<pre>'; var_dump($templates); die();

        $this->templates = $templates;

    }
```

register it

```
 sonata.admin.global_template_registry:
        class: App\Service\SonataTemplateRegistry
        public: true
        arguments: ['%sonata.admin.configuration.templates%', '@mea.contact']
```

class is fired - die() show templates but main template is not changed when i change here.

Update 2

in admin class when i get layout template i get correct   @SonataAdmin/layout1.html.twig

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {

        var_dump($this->configurationPool->getTemplate('layout'));
```

but it is not loaded, still see @SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig

UPDATE 3

I found a strange behavior - main page sonata admin - switching template works but already under the pages use the default template

UPDATE 4
I found something interesting , each admin panel has sub service like here :

```
php bin/console debug:container |grep app.admin.social
  app.admin.social.accounts                                                                     App\SocialManager\Admin\SocialAccountAdmin                                                      
  app.admin.social.accounts.template_registry                                                   Sonata\AdminBundle\Templating\TemplateRegistry                                                  
  app.admin.social.order                                                                        App\SocialManager\Admin\SocialManagementOrderAdmin                                              
  app.admin.social.order.template_registry                                                      Sonata\AdminBundle\Templating\TemplateRegistry
```

i override parameters :

```
parameters:
    sonata.admin.global_template_registry: App\Service\SonataTemplateRegistry
```

and service

```
sonata.admin.global_template_registry:
    class: App\Service\SonataTemplateRegistry
    public: true
    arguments: ['%sonata.admin.configuration.templates%', '@mea.contact']
```

so why sonata still use Sonata\AdminBundle\Templating\TemplateRegistry

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {


$this->getTemplateRegistry()
```

give Sonata\AdminBundle\Templating\TemplateRegistry

Comment: What do you mean with “but depends of logged user”? Can you give an example of what you’re trying to do?

Comment: If logged user belong to group customers has some ROLE  - show other layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use workaround by service tags.
First create your own Template registry and implement MutableTemplateRegistryInterface.
Then create compiler pass.

```
<?php

namespace App\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use App\Registry\TemplateRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

/**
 * Class SonataAdminTemplateRegistryPass
 * @package App\DependencyInjection\Compiler
 */
class SonataAdminTemplateRegistryPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        foreach ($container->findTaggedServiceIds('sonata.admin.template_registry') as $id => $tags)
        {
            //because @see src/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/DependencyInjection/Compiler/AddDependencyCallsCompilerPass.php:405
            $adminServiceId = str_replace(".template_registry", "", $id);
            $def            = $container->getDefinition($adminServiceId);
            $def->removeMethodCall('setTemplateRegistry');
            $def->addMethodCall('setTemplateRegistry', [new Reference(TemplateRegistry::class)]);
        }
    }

}
```

then add compiler pass to src/Kernel.php like this

```
protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $container->addCompilerPass(new SonataAdminTemplateRegistryPass());
}
```

And you will get always override TemplateRegistry in any admin class.
So you can implement your own logic in your own TemplateRegistry :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using single Twig template:

```
{# layout.html.twig #}
{# mutatis mutandis #}

{% extends app.user ?
    ('ROLE_ADMIN' in app.user.role ?
        'admin_layout.html.twig' :
        'customer_layout.html.twig'
    ) :
    'fallback.html.twig'
%}
```